# How to get the notice period shorter of 45 days, already passed 15 days?

Tags: work-environment, notice-period, middle-east

I am software engineer, right now, in Kuwait, working in construction company as draftsman (AutoCad). I'm very unhappy with my job, they have given the labour visa which I didn't know when I was coming from my home country, now working for 1 year I am making building plans for my current company.

My current boss wants me to become Civil Engineer, right now I am working part time also as a software engineer with some other startup and have one more job offer in the hand, but the problem is first he told me to stay and he will provide me good package and become civil engineer but coming from IT background, I'm unsure how can I become civil engineer, he wants me to undergo civil engineering also.

I refused his offer, now having one more offer in hand, he gave me the notice period before giving me transfer to another company, big problem was my visa that can be transferred from only construction to construction company but my new employer has provided me the construction company visa and he will transfer to the office visa but still i don't understand why my current boss making problem for me every time.

Now he wants me to serve notice period which is not applicable according to the labor law but I think according to his company rules, it is applicable, how to get transfer early?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I negotiate a reduced notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/how-can-i-negotiate-a-reduced-notice-period)

Comment: My story is completly different @David

Comment: @DavidK Not sure that advice centered around the UK as in that question you say is duplicate is relevant for Kuwait - most likely the customs and laws are markedly different.

Comment: (I cannot see the slightest duplicated aspect - but whatever.)  This should just be on "law" perhaps?

Comment: I dont know how to proceed not going to take any action against my company just simple waiting for the days to end of notice period.

Comment: So, to clarify... it sounds like you're in Kuwait.  Your current boss made requests of you that you didn't want to agree to.  You turned him down, since you had an offer in hand already.  He gave you notice that he was letting you go, but now he doesn't want to let you go until the notice is up.  Is that basically accurate?

Comment: If you want to know how to respond, we might be able to help you.  If you're just going to let the time run out, then you have no question to ask.

Comment: @Ben perfect observation. He knows that i am good at work may be that is the reason for not letting me go?

Comment: @Ben tell me how to respond ?

Comment: Have you consulted with a "*legal professional*" in your area?

Comment: Yes, i have consulted some persons, they are saying this is the worst case scenario in which i cannot take any legal action before 3 years of working now.

Comment: I now absolutely and totally do not understand anything, at all, about this question or the overall situation!

Comment: @Fattie Please read the comment of Ben he understood it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have three reasonable options.**

- You could finish out your notice period.  If the company you're intending to move to is willing to wait for you, and you would not find it overly toxic, this is the easiest route.  Certainly, he's not going to turn you into a civil engineer in less than a month and a half, and it will give you the time to finish up any projects you might have had.
- You could talk with a lawyer.  For an initial consultation, this will cost a smallish amount of time, but a potentially notable amount of money.  (It depends on how expensive the local lawyers are, as compared to how much money you make.)  That would give you a much clearer idea of what your options are.
- If you are unwilling or unable to pay for a lawyer, and the company you're hoping to move to isn't willing to wait for you, or specifically wants you sooner, you could ask them for help or advice.  They will know the ins and outs of visa transfer a lot better than we will, and already have reason to wish to help you.  You'll want to make sure that you're not being a burden on them, but they should be able to give you good advice at minimum, and may be able to give you some more direct assistance (depending on what the laws in question actually are).

edit: if you have already talked with lawyers, and they have told you that there is nothing you can do... then there is nothing you can do.  You either have to tough it out or convince him to let you go of his own accord.  The latter is sufficiently far away in scope that if you want advice on how to do that, you should probably make a separate question asking that specifically (including that you went to lawyers, and they said that you had no recourse).

edit 2: based on your comments, your old boss is now really *very* unhappy with you.  If you can help to fix that, or even reduce that, without agreeing to do extra work or stay for longer than you have to, then that is likely to help.  Otherwise, just keep your head down and tough it out.

Comment: Going to lawyers rather i have consulted my senior relatives who are working in Kuwait from decades, they are saying according to the law, i cannot take any action until i complete 3 years in my current company, Adding to your first option, i find the easiest route to the new company now, as the new company is ready to wait for me. I am also so underpaid in my current company due to the labor visa, my new company even providing me the basic salary which is very good for my career also.

Comment: But serving notice period in my current company when you don't have any work from last 6 months, i am feeling like i am doing nothing and i am sitting free for 1 month more. I find it very toxic when he gave me the notice period because i am the only one in this company who he gave the notice period, never happened before with any employer of this company.

Comment: @Singh If you are doing nothing, you may be able to convince your old boss to let go of you earlier, just so that he can stop paying you.  Still, it is only one month.  You can tough it out.